# Zepto/JQuery AJAX request automatically downloading media files from requested html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zepto

I need to make AJAX request for HTML content, but when I look into firebug it seems that request is downloading media files attached to requested html (images, CSS). How can I stop it? I need only plain text from PHP-genereted HTML.

```
$.ajax({
    type:     'GET',
    url:      'http://examplehost.com,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success:  function (data) {
        // SUCCESS CODE HERE
    },
    error:    function (xhr, type, error) {
        // ERROR CODE HERE
    },
    complete: function() {
        // ON COMPLETE CODE HERE
    }
});
```

I also must have possibility to run functions when request is complete!
Im using ZEPTO library, but its JQuery clone, so the functions are similar.

Comment: Are you trying to get contents from another domain? Did you try just to use `$.get`? Are you appending the content to a DOM element (then it will of course download all the assets.)?

Comment: According to ZEPTO documentation, $.get function have no "complete" callback. Im manipulating the data which I retrieve with zepto ( $(data).find(... ), not appending html contents to my html itself. Im building an array with data fetched from AJAX. Im getting contents from another domain.

Comment: Do you really need the complete callback (in addition to success)? Also, you shouldn't be able to get HTML via AJAX from a remote domain unless you are using CORS.

Comment: I have PHP "proxy" for that, with header "allow-origin-domain", so the request is possible. When im debuging in firebug i can see in "network" panel that the files i mentioned are beeing download when the request for html is send...

Comment: Then I'd guess that you are somehow appending this HTML to the DOM?

Comment: No, im loading data to variable, and then traversing through elements to find what I need, but im not adding that data to currently displeyed page. I dont know how to explain that. Im doing it like this -> var mydata = $(data).find('#someid').html(); and thats it. Im not appending the contents of html to DOM of my page...

Comment: You are right, apparently the wrapping (`$(data)`) makes the browser download the data, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5VN8/ and check what happens when you uncomment the wrapping.

Comment: See: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js#L156 and https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/zepto.js#L101 for what's happening

Comment: Uncommenting line with variable set results in sending GET request... So... Any idea how to stop this and retive only plain html text?

Comment: You need to process your data without the help of our beloved $ I guess (using plain String processing) as everything else will result in the creation of a DOM Element and the download of files. Do you have any influence on what's happening Server-side?